# How to use $routeParams in resolve

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise, resolve, angularjs-http

I use `$routeParams` like this right now:

My factory function:

```
angular.module('fifaApp')
  .factory('FifaService', ['$http',
    function($http) {
      var sdo = {
        getTeamDetails: function(code) {
          var promise = $http.get('api/team/' + code);
          promise.success(function(data, status, headers, conf) {
            return data;
          });
          return promise;
        }
      }
      return sdo;
    }
  ]);
```

Controller function:

```
.controller('TeamDetailsCtrl',
  ['FifaService','testt',
    function(FifaService,testt) {
      var self = this;
      self.team = testt.data;
    }
]);
```

config:

```
angular.module('fifaApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
.when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
    })
.when('/team/:code', {
      templateUrl: 'views/team_details.html',
      controller:'TeamDetailsCtrl as teamDetailsCtrl',
      resolve: {
          testt: ['$routeParams','UserService',
          function($routeParams, UserService) {
          return FifaService.getTeamDetails($routeParams.code);
      }]
  }
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
 });
});
```

But `views/team_details.html` does not show. Any ideas?
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calllback function don't have an ability to return data. Your ‘getTeamDeatails‘ method should return a promise insteaf of using callbacks, for that you need to return ’$http.get ’ which already returning promise object.

```
 getTeamDeatails: function() {
      var promise = $http.get('api/team');
      promise.then(function(resp){
        return resp.data;
      });
      return promise;
 }
```

Add missing FifaService dependency in resolve method

**Resolve**

```
resolve: { 
  testt: ['$routeParams', 'FifaService', 
    function($routeParams, FifaService ) { 
        return FifaService.getTeamDetails($routeParams.code); 
 }]
```

Comment: that does not help :/

Comment: Yes Reference error: Fifaservice is not defined. At $Routeprovider resolve test, it says. Did not see that.

Comment: Checkout my edit..you were missing FifaService dependency in resolve function

Comment: Ahh great! I do not need UserService as dependency as well. Thanks!

Comment: Oh..glad to here that..Thanks :)

Comment: still one problem remains. The images are not loaded if I use your solution :/

Comment: Its weird.. This code can never affect image loading part..you missed something else

Comment: I still do not get any data from `FifaService.getTeamDetails($routeParams.code)`. Do I need to have a `.then()` in `testt` resolve?

Comment: @user1665355 no need of it there

Comment: @user1665355 I can;t come on chat now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93491/discussion-between-user1665355-and-pankaj-parkar).

Answer (score 4):

I guess `$routeParams` doesn't work in `resolve`. Use `$route.current.params` instead:

```
getTeamDeatails: function() {
      var promise = $http.get('api/team');
      promise.then(function(resp){
        return resp.data;
      });
      return promise;
 }

resolve: { 
  testt: ['$route', 'FifaService', 
    function($route, FifaService ) { 
        return FifaService.getTeamDetails($route.current.params.code); 
 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $route.current.params.key instead. The $routeParams is updated only after a route is changed. So your code should look along those lines:

```
resolve: { 
    functionName: function($route) {
         console.log($route.current.params.key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it is your problem but you should use controllerAs parameter.

I mean do not use
controller:'TeamDetailsCtrl as teamDetailsCtrl'

but
controller:'TeamDetailsCtrl',
controllerAs: 'teamDetailsCtrl'

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: "Whether we use the controller key and define the renaming in it, or define it
separately using the controllerAs key, there is no functional difference. It is purely
a personal preference." from angular up and running book :)